# Assert one of the values in object to be the return value of a function

Tags: typescript, assertion

I have a list of options. Each have a label and a value. The value should be returned on click. Because I know the options beforehand (statically), I should be able to derive the possible return values for the onClick handler. How do I do this?

```js
import { FC, ReactNode } from "react";

type OptionsType = "shape" | "line" | "sourceUse";

type Option =
  | {
      clickable: true;
      label: ReactNode;
      value: string;
    }
  | { clickable: false };

interface Props {
  type: OptionsType;
  top: number;
  left: number;
  name: string;
  onClick:(value:string) => void; // (value: key in typeof OPTIONS[type].value) => void; 
}

const OPTIONS: Record<OptionsType, Option[]> = {
  shape: [
    {
      clickable: true,
      label: "Rename Entity",
      value: "rename",
    },
    { clickable: false },
    {
      clickable: true,
      label: "Add source",
      value: "add-source",
    },
    {
      clickable: true,
      label: "Add use",
      value: "add-use",
    },

    { clickable: false },

    {
      clickable: true,
      label: "Delete all Trades",
      value: "delete-trades",
    },
    {
      clickable: true,
      label: "Delete from Timeline",
      value: "delete-timeline-entity",
    },
  ],
  line: [],
  sourceUse: [],
};
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1av2w) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?